# Print all the Combinations that can give the given Number with `+` or `-` operators

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, combinations

Given an *array* of *integers* and number `num`.

I need to write a function `public static int printExpr(int[] a, int num)`

The function should print all the **combinations** that can give the number `num` with `+` or `-` operators, and to return the number of **combinations**.

The solution should be **recursive**

For example, for the *given array*:

`{1, 3, 6, 2}` and `num=4`

The output should be:

```
+3+1=4
+6-3+1=4
+2+3-1=4
+2+6-3-1=4
-2+6=4

5
```

---

**My attempt:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 3, 6, 2};
        System.out.println("\n" + printExpr(a, 4));
    }

    public static int printExpr(int[] a, int num) {
        return printExpr(a, num, 0, 0, "");
    }

    public static int printExpr(int[] a, int num, int i, int sum, String s) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= a.length)
            return 0;
        if (num == sum) {
            System.out.println(s+"=4");
            return 1 +  printExpr(a, num, i , 0,  "") ;

        }
        return printExpr(a, num, i + 1, sum, s + "")+printExpr(a, num, i + 1, sum + a[i], s + "+" + a[i]) + printExpr(a, num, i + 1, sum - a[i], s + "-" + a[i]) ;
    }
```

**My output:**

```
+1+3=4
+1-3+6=4

2
```

---

I think that this question is kind of [SubsetSum](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/).

What am I missing?

**Note** `LinkedList`, `HashSet`, etc. are not allowed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static int printExpr(int[] a, int num) {
        return printExpr(a, num, 0, 0, "");
    }

    public static int printExpr(int[] a, int num, int i, int sum, String s) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= a.length){
            if (num == sum) {
                System.out.println(s + "=4");
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        if (num == sum) {
            System.out.println(s+"=4");
            return 1;
        }

        return printExpr(a, num, i + 1, sum, s)+printExpr(a, num, i + 1, sum + a[i], s + "+" + a[i]) + printExpr(a, num, i + 1, sum - a[i], s + "-" + a[i]) ;
    }
```

Output:

```
+6-2=4
+1+3=4
+1-3+6=4
-1+3+2=4
-1-3+6+2=4

5
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, a quick recap on ***recursion***.

Every recursive implementation consists of two parts:

- **Base case** - a part that represents a set of simple edge-cases which should  terminate the recursion. The outcome for these edge-cases is known in advance. For this task, the first ***base case*** is when the target sum is reached and the *expression* has to be printed on the console and the *return value* has to be `1` (i.e. one combination was found). Another ***base case*** is a situation when *array* was fully discovered but the current sum differs from the target. For this case, return value will be `0`.
- **Recursive case** -  the part of the method where recursive calls are made and where the main logic resides.

There are tree alternative *branches* of execution in the ***recursive case***:

- we can either ignore it;
- contribute the target `sum` (add to the current string with `+` sign in front of it and subtract it from the target `sum`);
- or subtract it from the `sum` (add to the current string with `-` sign in front of it and add it to the target `sum`).

In all these cases, we need to advance the index by `1` while calling the method recursively.

In order to found the total number of combinations, we need to introduce a variable (*denoted as* `count` *in the code below*). And the result returned by every *recursive branch* will contribute that variable.

The code might look like this:

```
public static int printExpression(int[] arr, int sum) {
    return printExpression(arr, 0, "", sum);
}

public static int printExpression(int[] arr, int current, String expression, int sum) {
    if (sum == 0) { // base case - target sum has been reached
        System.out.println(expression);
        return 1;
    }
    if (current == arr.length) {  // base case - target sum wasn't reached and current index is out of bounds
        return 0;
    }
    // recursive case
    int count = 0;
    count += printExpression(arr, current + 1, expression, sum); // ignore current element
    count += printExpression(arr, current + 1, expression + "+" + arr[current], sum - arr[current]); // add current element (i.e. subtract from the target sum)
    count += printExpression(arr, current + 1, expression + "-" + arr[current], sum + arr[current]); // subtract current element (i.e. increase the target sum)
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int combinationCount = printExpression(new int[]{1, 3, 6, 2}, 4);
    System.out.println("Number of combinations: " + combinationCount);
}
```

**Output**

```
+6-2
+1+3
+1-3+6
-1+3+2
-1-3+6+2
Number of combinations: 5
```